# Why does nginx return 404 from mean server when loading assets?

Tags: networking, nginx, proxy, mean-stack, server-configuration

I have an nginx reverse proxy that cannot get assets from an upstream mean stack server. It's a single page app that is very small. The index file will load just fine but all assets respond with 404 not found. It works locally when I have `<base href="/">` but that does not work through the proxy. I've read and implemented the suggestions from [proxying nginx Express - 404 on static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419492/proxying-nginx-express-404-on-static-files) and [NginX proxying Nodejs/Express - 404 on static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700464/nginx-proxying-nodejs-express-404-on-static-files) and read [this article](http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-2-using-nginx-to-avoid-node-js-load/) about replacing express static routing with nginx to help me solve this issue but none have worked.

The request uri is simply

*mydomain.com/myApp*

and the folder structure looks like:

```
myApp
├── app
└── public
    ├── css
    ├── js
    └── views
```

nginx config:

```
   1  server {
   2     listen 80;
   3 
   4     server_name mydomain.com;
   5
   6     location ~ ^/myApp/(libs/|img/|js/|css/) {
   7         root /path/to/myApp/public;
   8         access_log off;
   9         expires max;
  10     }
  11
  12     location /myApp {
  13         proxy_pass http://mean-stack-ip:8080;
  14         proxy_http_version 1.1;
  15         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  16         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  17         proxy_set_header Host $host;
  18         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  19     }
  20 }
```

server.js:

```
   1 // server.js
   2 
   3 // modules =================================================
   4 var express        = require('express');
   5 var app            = express();
   6 var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
   7 var methodOverride = require('method-override');
   8 
   9 // set our port
  10 var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  11 
  12 // get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
  13 // parse application/json 
  14 app.use(bodyParser.json());
  15 
  16 // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
  17 app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
  18 
  19 // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  20 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  21 
  22 // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
  23 app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
  24 
  25 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
  26 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  27 
  28 // routes
  29 require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes
  30 
  31 // startup our app at http://localhost:8080
  32 app.listen(port);
  33 
  34 // shoutout to the user                     
  35 console.log('Server listening on port ' + port + ' ...');
  36 
  37 // expose app
  38 exports = module.exports = app;
```

app/routes.js:

```
   1 // app/routes.js
   2 
   3 module.exports = function(app) {
   4 
   5     // route to handle all angular requests
   6     app.get('/myApp', function(req, res) {
   7         res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html');
   8     });
   9 
  10 };
```

index.html:

```
   1 <!doctype html>
   2 <html lang="en">
   3 
   4 <head>
   5     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   6     <base href="/myApp/">
   7     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   8 
   9     <title>My App</title>
  10     
  11     <!-- CSS -->
  12     <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  13     <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  14     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  15 
  16     <!-- JS -->
  17     <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  18     <script src="libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  19     <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  20     <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  21 
  22     <!-- ANGULAR -->
  23     <script src="js/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
  24     <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
  25     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  26 </head>
  27 
  28 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
  29     <div id="body-container" class="container-fluid">
  30         
  31         <!-- Angular dynamic content -->
  32         <div ng-view></div>
  33 
  34     </div>
  35 </body>
  36 
  37 </html>
```

I'm new to mean stack and brand new to nginx so any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm essentially blocked from building anything further because I can't serve my apps!

Thanks in advance,

Amr

Comment: Im having a similar issue where I want to access a NodeJS application using `/myapp` in the nginx conf file. I can get it to serve the static `index.html` not other JS files are not found because of the incorrect redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try proxying all requests instead of just /myApp.

Comment: @AmrGaber could you please elaborate how you fixed it

Comment: If you have multiple services running behind the nginx gateway this wont work. Your might have `/app1` and `/app2` that need to be redirected to a specific port number.

Comment: @mortond then what is the solution for multiple apps?

Comment: @IsaacPak my solution to this problem was to create 2 .conf file directories, one directory was for applications which defined `server` domain level configurations for applications like `todo.example.com` or `skynet.example.com`. The other .conf directory was for `location`s like `/api1/` or `/api2`. These config files where included in my main nginx.conf file at different positions `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/apis/*.conf;` and `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/applications/*.conf;` For the `server` level configs the `location` was `/` and for API level the `location`s were `/api/` or `/endpoint/`

Comment: nice.  I have the same setup as the op.  But my solution was to add the app root directory to the express static function.  So in the op's case I would do something like:  app.use('/myApp', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in my logs when I using [docker container links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) to connect my containers like in some of the older documentation. [Docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) is the thing to use. I have another post with [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849456/nginx-reverse-proxy-404-on-static-files/47246164#47246164) and my web site www.starbug.com uses this and has links to my git repo with the full source.

I didn't want to duplicate my answer in the other post, but the basic idea is to create a docker network and refer to the containers by their names in the configuration file. This is what worked for me:

```
docker network create nginx-proxy

docker run --net nginx-proxy --name nginx-ss-00.starbug.com -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx-ss.starbug.com

docker run --net nginx-proxy --name aai-gunicorn-00 -d -p 8080:8080 aai-gunicorn
```

and in my nginx conf

```
server {

    server_name  www.starbug.com;
    listen       80;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {

        # TODO Assumes flask container is named aai-gunicorn-00 and running on port 8080
        proxy_pass http://aai-gunicorn-00:8080;

        # Redefine the header fields that NGINX sends to the upstream server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size 5M;

    }

}
```