# Nginx Nodejs & Express - 404 on static files

Tags: html, node.js, nginx, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a similar problem of this question:

- [NginX proxying Nodejs/Express - 404 on static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700464/nginx-proxying-nodejs-express-404-on-static-files)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/635210/node-js-express-nginx-static-file-paths-break-with-name-spaced-proxy-pass

This is my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
```

and in my node app:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, ROOT, 'public')));
```

and works if I use **www.mydomain.com** (with proxy_pass nginx configuration)

## Problem

If I want to use my app with : **www.mydomain.com/app1** instead **www.mydomain.com** using this nginx conf:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40985900/3957754

All works except my css. I get a 404 because html client expect a css with this path (**without /app**) :

```
www.mydomain.com/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

## Solution 1

In order to fix this, I must to hard code **app1** in css href :

```
 link(rel="stylesheet" href="/app1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

And a success css url is requested by html client:

```
www.mydomain.com/app1/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

## Solution 2

Instead **www.mydomain.com/app1**, We are obliged to use subdomains like **www.app1.mydomain.com**.

In this case, nginx configuration is easy and our app works. But We need to create more and more subdomains :S

## Attempts without success :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27715628/3957754
- https://serverfault.com/questions/635210/node-js-express-nginx-static-file-paths-break-with-name-spaced-proxy-pass

## Question

- Is there a way to make app independent of nginx configuration?
- A subdomains strategy is correct?
- Let us imagine a purchased web application to be used as  **www.mydomain.com/app1** because root domain **www.mydomain.com** is used.

  Need I to add **/app1/** to all static files references of my purchased application?

Thanks in advance.